# How to reverse legend labels in Flot stacked bar chart?

Tags: javascript, flot, reverse, legend

Basically it is all in the title. I pass a `json` object to my template. This is how it's build using python:

```
series = []
tab = []
for i,l in reversed(list(enumerate(ts_g))):
    try:
        z = l[0].split(";")

        start_z = ts_g[0][0].split(';')[0]
        tmp_d = {
            'data': [
            [float(start_z), float(z[1])],
            ],
            'label': str(s.description),
            'color':str(s.color)
            }
        series.append(tmp_d)
        tab.append([z[0],z[1],s.description])

    except Exception:
        raise Exception("couldn't get data from vsoil data field\n")


return series, tab.reverse()
```

All values are negatives so I want the legend to be displayed in reverse. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sorted: "reverse"`, as described in the [Customizing the Legend](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-legend) section of the documentation.  Note that this requires Flot 0.8, which is still technically a dev version, though it's due to replace 0.7 as the stable release in the next week or two.